# InnerHTML not working in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I've been trying to modify html from a Leaflet code, but it seems innerHTML doesnt work (I tried an alert with the click event and it works), is there another error in my code?, been trying different workarounds but so far nothing work, thanks!!

```
var points = [
        [-23.695266, -70.421018],
        [-23.705082, -70.424633],
        [-23.706943, -70.423570],
        [-23.714329, -70.422545]
];

var icono = L.icon({
    iconUrl: "images/ico.png",
    iconSize: [25, 41]
})

var markersArray = [];

for (var i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i] = new L.marker(points[i], {icon: icono}).addTo(map);
}


markersArray[0].on('click', function(e) {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Antofa";
        document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = "Latitud "+e.latlng["lat"]+", Longitud: "+e.latlng["lng"];
        document.getElementById("link_anchor").innerHTML = "Vid";
        document.getElementById("link_anchor").setAttribute("href", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anlOJqnvB0c");

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="info">
        <h1 id="name"></h1>
        <h2 id="coordinates"></h2>
        <h3 id="link"><a href="" target="_blank" id="link_anchor"></a></h3>
```

Comment: Please, create a [mcve] so we can see the actual error.

Answer (score 3):

The code provided in the question works fine:

```js
var points = [
  [-23.695266, -70.421018]
  /*,
    [-23.705082, -70.424633],
    [-23.706943, -70.423570],
    [-23.714329, -70.422545]*/
];

/*var icono = L.icon({
  iconUrl: "images/ico.png",
  iconSize: [25, 41]
})*/

var map = L.map("map").setView(points[0], 12);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var markersArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  markersArray[i] = /*new*/ L.marker(points[i], {
    //icon: icono
  }).addTo(map);
}

markersArray[0].on('click', function(e) {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Antofa";
  document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = "Latitud " + e.latlng["lat"] + ", Longitud: " + e.latlng["lng"];
  document.getElementById("link_anchor").innerHTML = "Vid";
  document.getElementById("link_anchor").setAttribute("href", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anlOJqnvB0c");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="info">
  <h1 id="name"></h1>
  <h2 id="coordinates"></h2>
  <h3 id="link">
    <a href="" target="_blank" id="link_anchor"></a>
  </h3>
</div>

<div id="map" style="height: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works, it seems that it doesnt work when I fix de divs height in %, could this be?, I tried this: #map {
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;

 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 margin-top:200px;
}

#info {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 top:200px;
}, and then the texts doesnt show on click, why is this?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it, I removed the absolute from the info div, the text was below the div, thats why i didnt see it when i clicked, thanks again